# HDTV 1080p HDMI/Component to VGA 1024x768 conversion yet maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: video, hdmi, vga, projector, 1080p

I recently inherited an older **XGA, 1024x768, 4:3 ratio LCD video projector.**
The projector only supports a D-Sub (VGA) input. My DirecTV satellite box outputs its video signal @ **standard 720p/1080p via component and HDMI outputs.**

**What are my options to convert my cable box's video HD signal so that it properly displays with my video projector at the proper aspect ratio of 16:9 at XGA resolution.**

Proper being a visual resolution of 1024x576, which 16:9 letter boxed resolution of 1024x768.  So the projector is displaying in 1024x768 mode but with letterbox bars to maintain 16:9 aspect ratio of the standard HD format.

Answer (score 1):

Either your projector is scaling "automatically" or it does not understand letterbox format of your HDTV

576 is by no means HD, it is highest of SD

PS my HD box displays ONLY 16:9 on digital outputs. That involves lame-scaled 4:3 channels. Letterbox options are available only for SCART and other analogue outputs.

PPS it is really hard to determine which is at fault - in my case HD box disproportions some 4:3 channels and i have no cure. In your case please ensure that scaling inside projector keeps proportions (i.e square pixels)

Comment: Like I said, it's a 4:3 projector.  Of course it doesn't display natively or scale any of the HD 16:9 aspect ratios.  This is why I need the aspect ratio conversion to be done before it sends at 1024x768 signal to the projector.  Like by a video converter box.